# Angular 5: Can't bind to property customDirective as it isn't a known property of customElement

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to write a feature toggle directive in Angular 5, for use across my whole application.

I have a feature toggle module, as so:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FeatureToggleDirective } from './feature-toggle.directive';
import { FeatureToggleService } from '../../common/feature-
toggle/feature-toggle.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    FeatureToggleDirective,
  ],
  exports: [
    FeatureToggleDirective,
  ],
  providers: [
    FeatureToggleService,
  ],
})
export class FeatureToggleModule { }
```

When I import this module into my app.module, like so:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routing,
        MetaModule.forRoot({provide: MetaLoader, useFactory: 
metaFactory}),
        HomeModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        NgReduxModule,
        StoreModule,
        SsoModule,
        ShellModule,
        BannerModule,
        ContentfulModule,
        PodsModule,
        BreakpointModule,
        AnalyticsModule,
        FeatureToggleModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        NonProdGuard,
        KillSwitchGuard,
        LoggerService,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AnalyticsInterceptor,
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { ... }
```

I get this error:

> Can't bind to 'appFeatureToggle' since it isn't a known property of
>   'div'. ("
>
> ]*appFeatureToggle="'feature'">
>
> "): ng:///StatusCheckModule/ResultsComponent.html@28:5 Property
>   binding appFeatureToggle not used by any directive on an embedded
>   template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and
>   all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
>
> [ERROR ->]
>
> "): ng:///StatusCheckModule/ResultsComponent.html@28:0 Error: Template
>   parse errors: Can't bind to 'appFeatureToggle' since it isn't a known
>   property of 'div'. ("

I understand what the error means, but I am a bit confused as to why it's happening.

When I import this module into the module of the app-need-help component and use it that way, it works just fine.

How come importing it into the app.module doesn't work in the same way?

Comment: basically, if you import a feature module (exporting a directive in your case) this directive is available only in the module importing. The best pratice here is to create a sharedModule exporting all application-wide components/pipes/directives. More on this => https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules#sharing-modules

Comment: Shouldn't this directive be available throughout the whole app if I import the module into the app module though? Or have I misunderstood how this should work?

Comment: A directive/component/pipe is available in a module if this module declares it, or if it imports a module exporting this directive/component/pipe.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when `declarations` comes before `exports`. I don't know why this happens, but this is the not working form:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    FeatureToggleDirective,
  ],
  exports: [
    FeatureToggleDirective,
  ],
  providers: [
    FeatureToggleService,
  ],
})
export class FeatureToggleModule { }
```

and this works:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    FeatureToggleDirective,
  ],
  declarations: [
    FeatureToggleDirective,
  ],
  providers: [
    FeatureToggleService,
  ],
})
export class FeatureToggleModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

check if your `FeatureToggleDirective` use any third party, make sure imported in `imports: []`